# cant .then Promise in react / redux / thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Completely new to JS, react, redux and thunk all together.
I am fetching data from an endpoint and I want to site to load / display an error if the fetch was resolved or rejected, but somehow I cant call .then on the fetch I return in my actioncreator.

```js
//projectApi.js
function add(project){
  const requestOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(
        project
    )
  };

  return fetch(config.apiUrl + "/projects", requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
}

function handleResponse(response) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (response.ok) {
      var contentType = response.headers.get("content-type");
      if (contentType && contentType.includes("application/json")) {
        response.json().then(json => resolve(json));
      } else {
        resolve();
      }
    } else {
      response.json().then(json => reject(json));
    }
  });
}
```

Then in my ActionCreator I'm doing this:

```js
//projectActions.js
function add(project){
  return dispatch => {
      dispatch(request());
      return projectApi.add(project)
        .then( project => {
          dispatch(success(project));
        },
        error => {
          dispatch(failure(error));
        }
      );
    };

  function request() {
  // left out for brevity
  }
  function success(project) {
  // left out for brevity
  }
  function failure(error) {
  // left out for brevity
  }
}
```

However, if I now try to .then my dispatch...

```js
//SomePage.js
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var project = { name: this.state.projectName };

    this.props.add(project).then(...);

  }

...

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
      add: (project) => {
          dispatch(projectActions.add(project));
      }
    };
}
```

I get "TypeError: this.props.add(...) is undefined", however all the actions are properly dispatched. (e.g. request, failure, success) and the store is updated.

Sorry if its a really stupid mistake.

Comment: you need to `return dispatch(projectActions.add(project))`

Comment: Where exactly am I missing it? Thanks for your help

Comment: OH I saw it ! ty its missing in the mapDispatchToProps...

Comment: If you are just passing the params through to the action creator, you can avoid this in the future by passing an object instead of function as the `mapDispatch` value: `const mapDispatchToProps = { add: projectActions.add }`.  Redux will automatically bind this to dispatch for you.